# Setting up channel for handling "editions"

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, channel, solspace-rating

I am trying to figure out the best way to structure my data.  I am building a site that is for rating items (generic term), but there is a new edition of the item every year. For this example, let's say that it is magazine editions.

The user would be able to search magazines and get a list returned back.  Let's say that the search results say National Geographic, Sports Illustrated, etc.

If they click on Sports Illustrated, they would go to a single page for sports illustrated, but within that page, they would be able to rate the content that they found in the January edition, as well as the February, March, etc. etc.

My understanding of ratings plugins is that they would actually be rating an entry like Sports Illustrated - January 2013, etc, etc.

What is the best way to set this up. I have done a basic website on EE, but nothing this complex involving ratings, members and all of that.

All input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue, I ended up creating two channels:

1) Magazine
2) Edition

and a relationship field between the two.

So for the example data, Magazine channel contains entries for National Geographic, Sports Illustrated, etc.  Edition channel contains 2013 National Geographic, 2012 National Geographic, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry about the delay. I just found your question on the list of unanswered questions.

My suggestion is to create a category_group for all magazines. Every magazine will be one category:

- National Geographic
- Sports Illustrated

You will use them for group the editions. Each individual edition go into one category of the group.

Comment: So I would create multiple category_group entries, such as one for Sports Illustrated, then each individual month would go into that category group?

Comment: I updated my answer.